# Load each progress bar from 0 to its value in multiple progress bar animation

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to add animation in grouped progress bar that will load each progress bar from 0 to its value. e.g in my sample code below I want to first load red progress bar then load the green progress bar. How can I do that?

Please check the code in [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dfkLexuv/8/).

html:

```
<div class="progress-bar-outer">
  <div class="progress-bar-inner">
  </div>
  <div class="progress-bar-inner2">
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.progress-bar-outer {
  width: 300px;
  height: 40px;
  flex: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: gray;
}
.progress-bar-inner {
  /* You can change the `width` to change the amount of progress. */
  width: 75%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}
.progress-bar-inner2 {
  /* You can change the `width` to change the amount of progress. */
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}

.progress-bar-outer div {
      animation:loadbar 3s;
    -webkit-animation:loadbar 3s;
}

@keyframes loadbar {
    0% {width: 0%;left:0;right:0}
}
```

Comment: Using delays and opacity will allow you to get the green bar to start where you want it as you can see by my answer... https://stackoverflow.com/a/45148563/2720927

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would transition `transform` instead for better performance. Use `translateX(-100%)` with `opacity: 0` to move them to their default, hidden position, then animate to `translateX(0); opacity: 1;` to put them in place. And just add an `animation-delay` to the green bar that matches the `animation-duration`

I made the bars semi-opaque to show when the animations fire.

```css
.progress-bar-outer {
  width: 300px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: gray;
  display: flex;
}

.progress-bar-inner {
  /* You can change the `width` to change the amount of progress. */
  width: 75%;
  background-color: red;
}

.progress-bar-inner2 {
  /* You can change the `width` to change the amount of progress. */
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}

.progress-bar-outer div {
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  animation: loadbar 3s forwards;
  -webkit-animation: loadbar 3s forwards;
  opacity: 0;
}

.progress-bar-outer .progress-bar-inner2 {
  animation-delay: 3s;
}

@keyframes loadbar {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- Learn about this code on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/progress -->

<div class="progress-bar-outer">
  <div class="progress-bar-inner">
  </div>
  <div class="progress-bar-inner2">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Michael for your answer. Can we update it so that green will load from where red is finished? also i tried to implement it in the css file but it wont do the animation at all. any idea why? Its a react component i am trying to apply the animation on

Comment: @User7354632781 you're welcome. Ah, that's why you were using flex! Updated with a way to use the same technique with flex.

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to update my css but it's not loading the progress bar one by one from its 0 value. Here's the link to my css https://jsfiddle.net/dfkLexuv/11/

Comment: @User7354632781 where is your html?

Comment: i dont have html calling it from react component jsx. updated link and added react code in javascript

Comment: @User7354632781 I'm not going to build your react app. It's your responsibility to post the relevant code in your OP and we fix the problem in the OP, not your personal project - unless your personal project was what you posted in the OP. You shouldn't expect us to build and fix your personal code after we've solved the problem in your OP. That said, if you can just post the rendered html and css, I can probably help you.

Answer (score 0):

Modified Michael Coker's answer to better reflect my interpretation of what you're asking for.

```css
.progress-bar-outer {
  width: 300px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: gray;
  position: relative;
}

.progress-bar-inner {
  /* You can change the `width` to change the amount of progress. */
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  z-index: 1;
}

.progress-bar-inner2 {
  /* You can change the `width` to change the amount of progress. */
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
  z-index: 2;
}

.progress-bar-outer div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; bottom: 0;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  animation: loadbar 3s linear;
  -webkit-animation: loadbar 3s linear;
  opacity: 1;
}

.progress-bar-outer .progress-bar-inner2 {
  animation-delay: 3s;
}

@keyframes loadbar {
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- Learn about this code on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/progress -->

<div class="progress-bar-outer">
  <div class="progress-bar-inner">
  </div>
  <div class="progress-bar-inner2">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply Transition to inner classes, add delays to secondary inner and use opacity to hide the element before transition begins.

```
.progress-bar-inner {
  animation:loadbar 2s;
  -webkit-animation:loadbar 2s;
}
.progress-bar-inner2 {
  -webkit-animation: loadbar 2s ease 2s forwards;
  animation: loadbar 2s ease 2s forwards
  animation-delay: 2s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
  opacity:0;
}

@keyframes loadbar {
    0% { width: 0%;left:0;right:0}
    1% { opacity: 1}
    100% { opacity: 1}
}
```

See working example:
https://jsfiddle.net/dfkLexuv/10/